# How to use sed to substitute subject to conditions?

Tags: sed

I have a text file line:

```
110254,TRCN,"OJSC "Transcontainer",LSE,1,2014-05-21,2014-11-28,,,2,,,0,
```

I would like to change the middle qoute character from `"` into a `\"`, but not the ones following or preceding a comma.

More generally, I would like to use sed to do the following:

- Ignore `/, *"/`
- Ignore `/" *,/`
- Ignore `/^ *"/`
- Ignore `/" *$/`
- Substitute all other `"` characters for `\"`

How do I go about doing this with sed?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the requirements, I believe that you can use :

```
sed 's/\([^,]\+\)"\([^,]\+\)/\1\\"\2/g'
```

It matches any `"` not followed nor preceeded by a comma, but with any other text, and replaces it with `\"`. For this I used `^` to negate the comma.

```
> echo '110254,TRCN,"OJSC "Transcontainer",LSE,1,2014-05-21,2014-11-28,,,2,,,0,' | sed 's/\([^,]\+\)"\([^,]\+\)/\1\\"\2/g'

110254,TRCN,"OJSC \"Transcontainer",LSE,1,2014-05-21,2014-11-28,,,2,,,0,
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not working for me and I'm trying to understand why. What is the + for?

Comment: @Ana the + matches at least a non comma character. Can you give an example of your expected output ?

Comment: The output that you got is the output I'm looking for. For some reason I'm just not getting it. I just get back the original line. Mac sed works differently?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/\([^,\\]\)"\([^,\\]\|$\)/\1\\"\2/g;ta' file
```